# How to use react hooks, to check props and render the proper component? (HOC)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hoc

Initially, there is no property *country* in props.
So, I need to show loading message if there is no *country* property in **props**, but the problem is that it's keep going to render loading element even property *country* does exist. So *country* property is appearing after sometime and hoc must to check for that. I'm not sure doing it properly.

```
const loadingComponent = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (props.country) return setLoading(false);
    }, [props]);

    return !loading ? <WrappedComponent {...props} /> : <p>Loading ...</p>;
  };
};
```

I'm trying to avoid using class order components. Or any alternative ways to create loading hoc? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need a state in this case. If the prop exists render the component, if not render loading:

```
const loadingComponent = WrappedComponent =>
  props => 
    props.country ? 
      <WrappedComponent {...props} /> 
      : 
      <p>Loading ...</p>;
```

I would create a more generic component, that accepts a predicate to check if loading is needed:

```
const loadingComponent = (predicate, WrappedComponent) =>
  props => 
    predicate(props) ? 
      <WrappedComponent {...props} /> 
      : 
      <p>Loading ...</p>;
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
const Wrapped = (props => 'country' in props, ComponentX);
```

Or check for other things

```
const Wrapped = (({ a }) => a < 5, ComponentY);
```